# Where is this stylesheet being loaded from?

Tags: php, css, wordpress

I am having a problem with a site I am developing with wordpress.

It happened after upgrading to the latest version (4.7)

Anyway. Go to the site www.scientized.com (just dummy content for now), and go the source. At around line 124 you see the tag `<style type="text/css" id="wp-custom-css">` and then after some css is loaded.

The thing is, is that this some of my old css code from way early. To make life easier and to isolate the problem I have delete all css in my child themes style.css as well as the custom css in the customizer, and delete jetpack just to be sure. Yet this css is being loaded from somewhere. I have file explored the crap out of my site trying to find where this is located, but couldn't find anything.

I have found that in the wp-includes/theme.php there is this function:

```
function wp_custom_css_cb() {
    $styles = wp_get_custom_css();
    if ( $styles || is_customize_preview() ) : ?>
        <style type="text/css" id="wp-custom-css">
            <?php echo strip_tags( $styles ); // Note that esc_html() cannot be used because `div &gt; span` is not interpreted properly. ?>
        </style>
    <?php endif;
}
```

so this wp_get_customer_css() function is calling the old css from somewhere -- I tried to follow the functions back to see where - but my php is not that good and got lost. Does anyone know where this is being loaded from?

I think I need to know where the JetPack custom css location is. I have read it is generated dynamically -- so I am not sure how to go about the problem.

Edit: I dont get the text box in the custom css area in customizer. Where is this text located?

[image]

Comment: What does this sentence mean: _"The thing is, is that this some of my old css code from way early. "_

Comment: Go to customizer then click on the css tab

Comment: Chek this link out https://en.support.wordpress.com/custom-design/editing-css/

Comment: ^ This guy beat me to it :) . Comment Edited.

Comment: @j08691 It means the css it is loading is from css code I wrote a long time ago. It has since been updated and replaced - yet it is somehow getting loaded. I have no idea how.

Comment: To everyone else -- I have of course looked at the css tab, css editor, customizer, blah blah. There is nothing. I have deleted everything in those text boxes.

Comment: Actually the problem still persists.

Comment: @Kevin.a The problem is I dont get the text field when I go there. I think something is very wrong. In that custom-design text box - where exactly does that get stored?

Answer (score 1):

> Edit: I dont get the text box in the custom css area in customizer. Where is this text located?

The Additional CSS content is stored in `wp_posts` database table as a separate record.  It's `post_type` is set to `custom_css`.  To find which post is assigned to the field, you need to look in the option `theme_mods_{your theme's slug}`.

For example, here is the one from my test Sandbox site which is running the Genesis Sample theme.  The post ID is 31, per the key `custom_css_post_id`.

[image]

### How do I check my site?

You can go directly into your database via phpMyAdmin and look in the `wp_options` table.  Or...you can do this:

```
add_action( 'init', 'check_custom_css_post_id_theme_mod' );
function check_custom_css_post_id_theme_mod() {
    var_dump( get_theme_mods() );
}
```

The above code will display the theme mods for your current theme.  Note the one that is keyed as `'custom_css_post_id'`.  That one holds the ID to the post for the CSS.

### How to Remove It

To remove a theme mod, you use `remove_theme_mod( 'custom_css_post_id' );`.  See [codex for the documentation](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/remove_theme_mod) on this construct.  It will remove the binding between the Additional CSS. How? It deletes the sub-option.

Note, it does not delete the post record, meaning you'll have an orphaned record in `wp_posts`.

Comment: Where do you call remove_theme_mod( 'custom_css_post_id' );?

Answer (score 0):

The wp-custom-css is loaded from custom css & js